# Jsoup - extracting data

Tags: java, jsoup

assuming i have the following html

```
<table id="tableMain">
  <tr>
    <td class="location">Location A text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="titleList">
     <tr>
      <td class="title">Title A.A</td>
      <td class="date">date</td>
      <td class="time">time</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="titleList">
     <tr>
      <td class="title">Title A.B</td>
      <td class="date">date</td>
      <td class="time">time</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="titleList">
     <tr>
      <td class="title">Title A.C</td>
      <td class="date">date</td>
      <td class="time">time</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="location">Location B text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="titleList">
     <tr>
      <td class="title">Title B.A</td>
      <td class="date">date</td>
      <td class="time">time</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="titleList">
     <tr>
      <td class="title">Title B.B</td>
      <td class="date">date</td>
      <td class="time">time</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="titleList">
     <tr>
      <td class="title">Title B.C</td>
      <td class="date">date</td>
      <td class="time">time</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There are two locations: Location A and Location B. Each location have multiple title list where each list contains title, date and time.

I am able to extract the locations but I don't know how to extract the titlelist and map to its respective location.

This is how i extract the location:

```
File input = new File("/home/user/htmlcontent.txt");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://www.example.com");

Elements elements = doc.select("table#tableMain").select("location");
for (Element e: elements) {
  system.out.println(e.text());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements elements = document.select("#tableMain tr:has(td.location) + tr");

    for (Element element : elements) {
        String location = element.previousElementSibling().select("td.location").text();

        System.out.printf("Current location: '%s'%n", location);

        Elements titleLists = element.select("#titleList > tbody > tr");

        for (Element tr : titleLists) {
            String title = tr.select("td.title").text();
            String date = tr.select("td.date").text();
            String time = tr.select("td.time").text();

            System.out.printf("Title: %s, Date: %s, Time: %s%n", title, date, time);
        }
    }
```

You can find full code here - https://gist.github.com/wololock/b0e31cb174123d463e3e

The most important part in this example is the selector used for selecting rows that don't contain location information:

```
document.select("#tableMain tr:has(td.location) + tr")
```

To achieve this firstly we ask for those `tr`s that have `td.location` and from that point we ask for sibling elements `... + tr`. From this point we have a reference to the rows with nested `#titleList` tables. Before you start selecting data from nested tables you can extract the location information with:

```
element.previousElementSibling().select("td.location").text()
```

I used iterating over:

```
element.select("#titleList > tbody > tr")
```

and select single data at a time, e.g. title, date, time. It's not the most efficient solution, it depends on how many rows you may have in your source html. Although optimizing this for a large set of data shouldn't be any problem.

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: hey @szymon, thank you for explaining. it helps. with your help im able to extract the info i needed.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help you. Take care!